# How to do for loops without overwriting?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a large data.frame called rain with information of many species mesured in different plots at different times (census), from which I want to extract the information. This data frame have many collumns, and in dataF2 I want to keep the same structure however I want to extract from rain the information of the penultimate census (Census.No is one of the collumns of rain) in each plot (Plot.Code is another one). In idx3 I have the information of the number of the penultimate census for each plot.

It's easy to do it for one plot

```
data1<- rain[Plot.Code==idx3[1,1] & Census.No==idx3[1,2],]
```

I've been trying to do for loops in R.. but I keep overwriting my data.frame and ending up just with the last loop.

```
dataF2<- data.frame(nrow= nrow (rain), ncol = ncol (rain))
summary (dataF2)
for (i in 1:length (idx3[,1])){
dataF2<- rain[Plot.Code==idx3[i,1] & Census.No==idx3[i,2],] 
}
```

Here I want to extract from a data frame the information of the penultimate census in each plot (`ixd3` contains this information of what was the penultimate census in each plot).
I've tried many things, like:

```
dataF2<- data.frame(nrow= nrow (rain), ncol = ncol (rain))
for (i in 1:length (idx3[,1])){
data1<- rainfor[Plot.Code==idx3[i,1] & Census.No==idx3[i,2],] 
dataF2<- rbind (data1[i])
}
```

But nothing worked.. my problem is that it keeps overwithin on dataF2!

Cheers!!!

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you intended by `data.frame(nrow= nrow (rain), ncol = ncol (rain))`? What do you expect the dimensions of that object to be? Can you give an example of what you expect the input and output to look like?

Comment: I agree with @joran - it would be a lot easier to understand if you added a short sample dataframe.

Comment: I have a large data.frame called `rain` with information of many species mesured in different plots at different times (census), from which I want to extract the information. This data frame have many collumns, and in dataF2 I want to keep the same structure however I want to extract from rain the information of the penultimate census (`Census.No` is one of the collumns of `rain`) in each plot (`Plot.Code` is another one). In idx3 I have the information of the number of the penultimate census for each plot.

Comment: It's easy to do it for one plot `data1<- rainfor[Plot.Code==idx3[1,1] & Census.No==idx3[1,2],]` but when I try to do for many it keeps overwriting!

Comment: Before the loop, do `data1 <- list()`; and within the loop, assign with `data1[[i]] <-`.

Comment: Thank you @Frank! It worked.. now I just have to convert the list `data1` in a data frame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clarifications in the comments helped somewhat, but reproducible examples are always better. Let's start at the beginning:

```
dataF2<- data.frame(nrow= nrow (rain), ncol = ncol (rain))
```

This is wrong. I *think* that you're trying to create an empty data frame with the same dimensions as your data frame `rain`. If you examine `dataF2` you'll see that this is far from what you have done with this line. If you read the documentation for the function `?data.frame` it will become clear that there are no arguments called `nrow` and `ncol`. What you probably intended was something like this:

```
dataF2 <- rain
dataF2[] <- NA
```

Inside your `for` loop you are overwriting your entire data frame because....you are overwriting your entire data frame.

```
dataF2<- rain[Plot.Code==idx3[i,1] & Census.No==idx3[i,2],]
```

This assigns something to `dataF2`, replacing it completely. If you want to assign to just a single *row* of `dataF2` you need to assign to that specific row:

```
dataF2[i,] <- rain[Plot.Code==idx3[i,1] & Census.No==idx3[i,2],]
```

I can't absolutely assure that this will work correctly, since you haven't provided a sufficiently detailed example, so I'm not sure that all the dimensions will coincide properly when you index on `i`. But this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you @joran.. my main problem in understanding how to save the data from the for loops... `dataF2[i,] <- rain[Plot.Code==idx3[i,1] & Census.No==idx3[i,2],]` because `i` is related to the lines in `idx3`.. and I have much more lines in `rain` and will have in `data1` than that. Cheers!